# Counting randomly 1 or 2 up with jQuery counter and use a cookie to save the number when it reaches 97

Tags: jquery, counter

I am completely new. Maybe someone can help?

I'm trying to make a counter that increments my number by 0, 1 or 2 every X seconds.
The number will start on 87 and work it's way up to 97. Increasing by 0, 1 or 2 each time.

If the user reloads the page, the counter just continues, and when the number reaches 97, it just stops there and show the number 97 - also on reload

So far, I have this that works

HTML:

```
<p id="offer">87</p>
```

In script tags:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var number = parseInt($('#offer').text()) // Getting my number from the p id


    // Called the function in each second
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
            $('#offer').text(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 1);
        
        if (number > 97) {
            clearInterval(interval); // If exceeded 97, stop
        }
    }, 1000); // Run for each second
});
```

And this is how I tried to increase it by 0, 1 or 2, but this didn't exactly work. It shows either 0, 1 or 2, but it does not add it to my number.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var number = parseInt($('#offer').text()) // Getting my number from the p id


    // Called the function in each second
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
            $('#offer').text(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 2)) + 0);
        
        if (number > 97) {
            clearInterval(interval); // If exceeded 97, stop
        }
    }, 1000); // Run for each second
});
```

And where and how should I add the cookie part, to "save" the number for each pageload?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to achieve here `$('#offer').text(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 2)) + 0);`

Comment: _"...but it does not add it to my number"_ - Because you never actually add (`+`) the random number to `number`

Comment: @SahilGrover - I'm trying to take my number in offer, and add either 0, 1 or 2 to that number.

Comment: @Andreas, if I try this, nothing happens at all: $('#offer').text + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 2)) + 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your incrementer at the moment is that you never add the new random value to the existing one; the new value is displayed by itself.

To store the value in the element as the increment is happening I would suggest using localStorage over cookies for simplicity. All you need to do in this instance is set the value in localStorage as it's updated in the interval, and read the value in to the text of the element on load. Something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $offer = $('#offer');
  
  let storedNumber = localStorage.getItem('number') || 87;
  $offer.text(storedNumber);
        
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    let number = parseInt($offer.text(), 10);
    if (number > 97) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }
    
    number += Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);    
    $offer.text(number);
    localStorage.setItem('number', number);
  }, 1000);
});
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/78otjbgq/1/) - note the example is in a Fiddle here as SO snippets are sandboxed and don't support localStorage.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I was not aware of the localStorage. When I try this on my live site though, it just returns the value NaN instead of the number. As in: "NaN have already tested this offer"

Comment: That's very odd as the `|| 87` should set the default value if nothing exists in localStorage

Comment: Aha! It works from incognito mode. A chrome extension I may have that is messing it up? Do you know if that would be an issue for my actual visitors as well, or would such errors mostly exist because my spesific chrome install have issues? Anything I can do about it?

Comment: Do you know which Chrome extension is blocking it? I use several and had no issues. It's more likely that key was already in localstorage for your site and confused the logic. Use devtools to clear the localstorage and give it another try

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. I deleted the cookies from the chainlock in the url field on chrome. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help